# Table is not outputting into my plan.php web page

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

$plan = array();
    $plan[0] = array();
        $plan[0]['price'] = '15.99';
        $plan[0]['size'] = 'Large';
        $plan[0]['toppings'] = 'Mushroom & Beef';
        $plan[0]['extras'] = 'Drizzle';
    $plan[1] = array();
        $plan[1]['price'] = '20.99';
        $plan[1]['size'] = 'Large';
        $plan[1]['toppings'] = 'Steak + Cheddar cheese';
        $plan[1]['extras'] = 'Drizzle + Stuffed crust';
    $plan[2] = array();
        $plan[2]['price'] = '10.99';
        $plan[2]['size'] = 'Medium';
        $plan[2]['toppings'] = 'Beef';
        $plan[2]['extras'] = 'Drizzle';
    $plan[3] = array(); 
        $plan[3]['price'] = '15.99';
        $plan[3]['size'] = 'Medium';
        $plan[3]['toppings'] = 'Beef + Olives';
        $plan[3]['extras'] = 'Drizzle + stuffed crust';
    $plan[4] = array();
        $plan[4]['price'] = '5.00';
        $plan[4]['size'] = 'Small';
        $plan[4]['toppings'] = 'Beef';
        $plan[4]['extras'] = 'None';

?>

    <?php
    function showPizza($maximum) {
        global $plan;

        $table = "<table border=1>
                <caption>Under $$maximum</caption>
                <tr><th>Price</th><th>Size</th><th>Toppings</th><th>Extras</th>
                \n";

        foreach ($plan as $items) {
            $price = $items['price'];
            $size = $items['size'];
            $toppings = $items['toppings'];
            $extras = $items['extras'];

            if ($price <= $maximum) {
                $table .= "<tr> <td>$price</td> <td>$size</td> <td>$toppings</td> <td>$extras</td> </tr>\n";
            }
        }
        $table .= "</table>";
    }
    ?>
    
    <body>
    <div class="prices">
        <div class="links">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="?price=20">$20 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=15">$15 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=10">$10 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=5">$5 and under</a></b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
        <?php
            echo $table;
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['price'])) {
        $userSelection = $_GET['price'];
    } else {
        $userSelection = 100;
    }

    showPizza($userSelection);

    ?>
```

I am trying to practice making a filter with different price points.

I got my code to work initially but I wanted to move the `<table>` somewhere else in my code so I put it in a `$table` variable, but my `$table` variable is not showing when I echo it into my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$table` only exists within the `showPizza` function, so `echo $table` can't output anything from outside the function. You really need to make the function return a value which you can then echo.

Also, you should avoid using global variables wherever possible. I corrected that too, plus a minor syntax error.

e.g.

```
<?php
    function showPizza($maximum, $plan) {

        $table = "<table border=1>
                <caption>Under $maximum</caption>
                <tr><th>Price</th><th>Size</th><th>Toppings</th><th>Extras</th>
                \n";

        foreach ($plan as $items) {
            $price = $items['price'];
            $size = $items['size'];
            $toppings = $items['toppings'];
            $extras = $items['extras'];

            if ($price <= $maximum) {
                $table .= "<tr> <td>$price</td> <td>$size</td> <td>$toppings</td> <td>$extras</td> </tr>\n";
            }
        }
        $table .= "</table>";
        return $table; //return the value
    }
    ?>
    
    
    <body>
    <div class="prices">
        <div class="links">
            <ul>
                <li><b><a href="?price=20">$20 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=15">$15 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=10">$10 and under</a></b></li>
                <li><b><a href="?price=5">$5 and under</a></b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['price'])) {
        $userSelection = $_GET['price'];
    } else {
        $userSelection = 100;
    }

    $pizzatable = showPizza($userSelection, $plan); //get the result of showPizza (i.e. a HTML string) and put it in a variable
    echo $pizzatable;
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a bit of an order of operations thing going here as well as some minor syntax.

I would additionally advise against using global variables and instead pass `$plan` as a second argument to `showPizza`.

The `$table` variable is inside the `showPizza()` function and not returned and is therefore not accessible by the page.

Furthermore whilst `$$variable` is technically valid PHP, it's not what you're looking for here and it's not escaped in the string. It's used if you want the variable *name* to be variable and is useful in some cases.

so your code would be more like

```php
function showPizza($maximum,$plan) {

        $table = "<table border=1>
                <caption>Under ".$maximum."</caption>
                <tr><th>Price</th><th>Size</th><th>Toppings</th><th>Extras</th>
                \n";

        foreach ($plan as $items) {
            $price = $items['price'];
            $size = $items['size'];
            $toppings = $items['toppings'];
            $extras = $items['extras'];

            if ($price <= $maximum) {
                $table .= "<tr> <td>$price</td> <td>$size</td> <td>$toppings</td> <td>$extras</td> </tr>\n";
            }
        }
        $table .= "</table>";
        return $table; //return the value
    }
```

Then you would call it in a similar way to the other example.

---

As another minor note, an easier way to declare your array (which I would assume is actually being stored in a db rather than hard coded is:

```php
$plan[]=[
    'price'=>'15.99',
    'size'=>'Large',
    'toppings'=>'Mushroom & Beef',
    'extras'=>'Drizzle',
];
$plan[]=[
    'price'=>'20.99',
    'size'=>'Large',
    'toppings'=>'Steak + Cheddar cheese',
    'extras'=>'Drizzle + Stuffed crust',
];
// etc...
```

`[]` is shorthand for `array()`

`$plan[]=` will push the assignment into the next key

`['key'=>'value']` will set array keys and values respectively

As you can see this can be "chained" for multiple declarations at once.